# Problema en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola buenas tardes tengo una duda sobre como prodria realizar un codigo ya que en la forma que me aparece tengo un erro pero lo quisiera solucionar y para que el Id no sea siempre el mismo y se pueda cambiar  atravez de un Edit Text.Entonceese me gustaria que me pudieran ayudar para saber como poder implementar un id al realizar diferentes compras. Estuve buscando de como realizar esto, pero no encontre en ningun sitio de como realizarlo

MainActiviy

```
package app.ejemplo.proyectoapp;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import app.ejemplo.proyectoapp.Config.Config;

import static app.ejemplo.proyectoapp.Config.Config.setPAYPAL_CLIENT_ID;


public class ActivityPaga extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton m1;
TextView m2;
static String s = "";





private static final int PAYPAL_REQUESET_CODE=7171;





private static PayPalConfiguration config = new 
PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
        .clientId(MainActivity3.PAYPAL_KEY);
Button btnPayNow;
EditText txtMonto;
String monto="";
private  TextView txtv;
private String ids="";


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this,PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paga);
    String dato = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
    s=dato;

    txtv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tc);
    ids=txtv.getText().toString();




    //Iniciar servicio paypal

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    startService(intent);

    m1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnback9);
    btnPayNow=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnoagar);
    txtMonto= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMontos);


    btnPayNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            procesarPago();
        }
    });


















    m1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new 
 Intent(ActivityPaga.this,SegundoActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(ActivityPaga.this, "Bienvenido de vuelta", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}

private void procesarPago() {

    //recibir monto del edit text
    monto=txtMonto.getText().toString();

    PayPalPayment payPalPayment=new PayPalPayment(new 
BigDecimal(String.valueOf(monto)),"MXN","pagado por isai",PayPalPayment
    .PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    Intent intent=new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUESET_CODE);




}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable 
Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUESET_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirmation = 
data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirmation != null) {
                try {
                    String paymentDetails = 
 confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, 
 activity_detallespago.class).putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)
                            .putExtra("PaymentAmount", monto));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

}

MainActivity2

```
package app.ejemplo.proyectoapp.Config;


 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import app.ejemplo.proyectoapp.R;

 public class Config extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView txt;
private static String s;

public TextView getTxt() {
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tc);
    s=txt.getText().toString();
    return txt;
}











public static final String PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=getTxt;


}
```

XML1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ActivityPaga">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:background="#3792D8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnback9"
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:tint="#3792D8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arr" />


</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtMontos"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="252dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Monto a pagar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnoagar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="276dp"
    android:text="Pagar"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtMontos"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.188" />
```

XML2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ID"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="290dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

y no me deja pasarlo en la variable PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
O me gustaría que el id se pueda cambiar

```
package com.technxtcodelabs.paypal;

public class PaypalConfig {
public static final String PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID =             "AbCoUEWWWbaZ_BkuygA9puGqIEYlO_6ZemMVOWF22UJMBm2GL5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

}

Comment: El primer problema es que PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID no es una variable, sino que lo estas declarando como constante el segundo es que en getTxt() estas devolviendo un TextView en lugar de tu String s y debes llamarlo de esta forma ID=getTxt()

Comment: como lo podria cambiar ? no me funciono. si lo podrias explicarlo o escribirlo para entenderlo mejor porfavor!

Comment: Por favor agrega el codigo de tu layout y el metodo onCreate

Comment: ya lo añadí amigo